# Show NextJS website Inside Laravel project built with blade

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, next.js

I have a laravel project which is completely built using blade template. And I have a nextJS project which is on a different repository. Now I am in a situation where I want to show the Nextjs project inside of the laravel project and I want to pass login tokens, sessions from the laravel project to the Nextjs project. Is it possible?
I tried using file_get_contents() function to integrate the Nextjs project inside the laravel project. But it doesn't help because I cannot pass tokens, sessions.

Comment: Have you considered loading the nextjs project as an iframe in your laravel project? You can set values to the local storage of the iframe